# How to marshal Objects generated with wsimport (xsd/wsdl) to xml in android?

Tags: android, xml, jaxb, marshalling, wsimport

How to marshal Objects generated with wsimport (xsd/wsdl) to xml in android?
Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [JAXB xjc tool](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html) to give you the required java classes but then change the XML annotations to match the [Simple XML](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) equivalent ones and then use them in the Android project.

Comment: Does Simple XML provide an equal annotation for every annotation in generated through JAXB xjc?

Comment: @Dirk: You should find an equivalent for each. I would be very surprised indeed if you could not make it work.

Comment: Isn't there perhaps a solution using some JavaME stuff in any way?

Comment: I'm not sure, I have not really looked into doing it another way. To be frank, I just write the XML Classes from scratch. Usually they are not even that large.